# Move ul list below div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move this ul below a div, I am not even sure if this is the perfect way to do it as well,

Here is the code,

**HTML**

```
<div class="first">
    <div id="Pic">
        <img src="http://48jwh53mcwj217jvx11dcwjj.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/avatar-2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="Name" class="left"> <span>User 1</span>

    </div>
    <div id="contactDetails" class="left">
        <ul style="float: left;">
            <li>
                <img src="https://tutorials.hostmonster.com/help_media/email.png"><span id="Email">user1@gov.com</span>

            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="https://tutorials.hostmonster.com/help_media/email.png"><span id="PhoneNumber">000000</span>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#Pic img {
    width: 128.5px;
    height: 128px;
    /* padding: 10px 7px 10px 7px; */
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
#Name {
    font-family:"Segoe UI Light", "Segoe UI", "Segoe", Tahoma, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.3em;
    color: #777;
    font-weight: 200;
}
.left {
    float:left;
}
```

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/fc2oya05/1/

**What I want it to look like**

[image]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/fc2oya05/6/ No need to float them left actually

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fc2oya05/7/

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at your [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fc2oya05/5/)

You need to remove the float from your div,

```
.left{
/* float:left; */
}
```

And you should replace the float in your ul with the following to remove the bullets in your list

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
```

Comment: The only answer addressing the real problem with the original code, imho. +1! //edit: although four minutes after Abhitalks posted the solution in a comment to the question.

Comment: Oh, i am sorry for that. When i opened the question there was no comment. By the time i posted it... i was too late. I upvoted the Abhitalks' answer as it was the correct and faster one

Answer (score 2):

ADD the following code in your css file: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fc2oya05/4/)**. If you want to be specific, add class / ID for `<ul>`

```
ul{
    clear:both;
    font-size:12px;   
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
li{
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap Name and ContactDetails to another div having class `left`:

HTML:

```
<div class="first">
    <div id="Pic">
        <img src="http://48jwh53mcwj217jvx11dcwjj.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/avatar-2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="left">
        <div id="Name"> <span>User 1</span></div>
        <div id="contactDetails">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img src="https://tutorials.hostmonster.com/help_media/email.png" class="left"><span id="Email">user1@gov.com</span>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="https://tutorials.hostmonster.com/help_media/email.png" class="left"><span id="PhoneNumber">000000</span>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#Pic img {
    width: 128.5px;
    height: 128px;
    /* padding: 10px 7px 10px 7px; */
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#Name {
    font-family: "Segoe UI Light","Segoe UI","Segoe",Tahoma,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.3em;
    color: #777;
    font-weight: 200;
}

#contactDetails ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style:none;
}

#contactDetails ul li img {
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.left{
    float:left;
}
```

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fc2oya05/8/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="Name" class="left">
```

remove class form name id

```
<div id="Name">
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fc2oya05/10/)

Answer (score 1):

wrap name and details in one div `<div class="userDetails"></div>` and remove class `left` to some elements. Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fc2oya05/12/)

Answer (score 1):

You can check with the below link. You just have to remove float: left.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fc2oya05/15/)

```
.left{
     margin-left:13%;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
.UIClass{
    float: left;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Here is My [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kri4shna/px9khLoj/)

Answer (score 1):

You can check with the below link.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/fc2oya05/16/)

```
#Email
{
    margin-left:10px;
}
#PhoneNumber
{
   margin-left:10px; 
}
```